# Find c+f f the sum of any four consecutive numbers from a, 8, b, c, d, e, f, 2 is equal to 17

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Each entry in the list of numbers below is a Positive Integer:

a, 8, b, c, d, e, f, 2

If the sum of ANY four consecutive terms in the list is 17, what is the value of c + f?

Comment: The value of $c+f$ can not be determined from that, are you sure you got the question correct? The solution is $7-t, 8, t, 2, 7-t, 8, t, 2$, here we get $c+f=2+t$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** : You are given that

1. $a+8+b+c=17$
2. $8+b+c+d=17$
3. $b+c+d+e=17$
4. $c+d+e+f=17$
5. $d+e+f+2=17$

Can you use these to find $c+f$? For example if you subtract 2 from 1 you get $a=d$. When you subtract 5 from 4 you get $c=2$. Try playing around with these five equations.